# How to increment paragraph object in word document using python-docx?

Tags: python, python-docx

I'm searching word documents to get descriptions of things that are written in the docs. However, these docs are not all formatted the same. But one thing that is consistent is the text block I want is always after the title 'Description'. So I'd search for 'Description' then hope to get the text of the next paragraph object after it. How an I increment the paragraph object (so to speak)?

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        doc = docx.Document(os.path.join(rootdir, file))
        for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
            if 'Description' in paragraph.text:
                print(paragraph[i+1].text) #I know you can't do i+1 but
                                           #that's essentially what I want to do
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach would be:

```
paragraphs = list(doc.paragraphs)

for i in range(len(paragraphs)):
    paragraph = paragraphs[i]
    if 'Description' in paragraph.text:
        print(paragraphs[i+1].text)
```

If you know for sure that the description label appears in a paragraph with `Heading 1` style, you could further qualify heading paragraphs so you don't get false positives on a paragraph that just happens to use that word.

Comment: Ah it tells me in this line `print(paragraph[i+1].text)` that the paragraph object does not support indexing, when it clearly seems to when applied elsewhere...? @scanny

Comment: Sorry @Vince, that should be `print(paragraphs[i+1].text)`, apologies for the typo. I've fixed it in the example. The Paragraph object does not support indexed access, which makes sense because it's not a collection. However, the value returned from Document.paragraphs is already a list, which of course supports indexing, so you could simplify the first line to `paragraphs = doc.paragraphs`.

Comment: If you're talking about some sort of behavior like Paragraph.next, like a paragraph supporting indexed access relative to itself, then no, that capability is not present.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to extract text and search that way, [python-docx2txt](https://github.com/ankushshah89/python-docx2txt) will give you less headaches. It was adapted from python-docx.